# Limiting simultaneous large file uploads in Play 2.3

Tags: file-upload, playframework-2.3

**TL;DR: Is it possible to specify the ExecutionContext for an Action's body parser? Or is there another way to limit the number of possible simultaneous large file uploads?**

Let's say we have an async action with a body parser that allows large file uploads (i.e., 100MB for an application that has a 1GB heap). We should be concerned about memory consumption if a lot of people want to upload large files at the same time because of the following statement in the Play Framework 2.3 documentation:

> Text based body parsers (such as text, json, xml or formUrlEncoded) use a maximum content length because they have to load all of the content into memory.

[Source: Play 2.3 Body Parsers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaBodyParsers)

Then, in addition to increasing the maximum content length for these file uploads, it seems to make sense to put large file uploads in their own thread pool to limit the number of possible concurrent threads that are uploading large files.

We can assign a Future to a specific thread pool by passing the ExecutionContext for that thread pool.

```
Future { ... }(myExecutionContext)
```

However, in this case, the parsing of the body appears to happen somewhere in framework code and it's not clear whether the application programmer has the opportunity to specify which thread pool should be used for the parsing.

What is the best way to limit the number of simultaneous large file uploads in Play 2.3?